# Running sync adapter periodically

Tags: android

I have implemented sync adapter functionality in my application. I am allowing the user to use the app in offline mode and whatever are the changes in the database during that offline mode are saved in a table and I want to sync that table's data to the server according to the periodic sync functionality.
I have given the options in settings as hourly,daily and weekly sync. 
The problem that I am facing is that the table's data is synced as soon there is an internet connection available despite of the sync frequency selected by the user. Please help me to resolve this issue

Comment: Have you create any service like alarm service or like that to invoke periodically for sync process?

Comment: I think the problem with the flag you have to only sync if the condition is match with the user set period may be you are directly sync when find connection this may be the problem.

Comment: I am not using any alarm service. I will give an example. Suppose the user has selected weekly sync from the settings and has used the app in offline mode. Then as soon as the user turns on the internet connection then the sync starts. If suppose the user does the same thing twice each day then the data will be synced twice. The weekly sync functionality is not used then

Comment: Thats why i'm pointing to the point to the flag i mean sharedpreferences because your way is not proper

Comment: remember that the OS will fire the sync adapter when it thinks is best - so if you miss one and have one pending it will probably just execute when you get connected again

Answer (score 0):

Look this simple code

```
public class TimerReceiverSyncInterval extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("TAG", "Sync OnReceive--");


    scheduleAlarms(context);
    context.startService(new Intent(context, NotificationServiceSyncInterval.class));

}

public static void scheduleAlarms(Context paramContext) {

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    String[] splited = mPrefs.getSyncTime().split("\\s+");
    if (mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Minute")) {

        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, Integer.parseInt(splited[0]));
    } else if (mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Hour")) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, Integer.parseInt(splited[0]));
    }

    AlarmManager localAlarmManager = (AlarmManager) paramContext.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent localPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(paramContext, 0,
            new Intent(paramContext, NotificationServiceSyncInterval.class), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    if (mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Minute")) {

        localAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                Integer.parseInt(splited[0]) * (60 * 1000), localPendingIntent);

    } else if (mPrefs.getSyncTime().contains("Hour")) {

        localAlarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
                Integer.parseInt(splited[0]) * (60 * 60 * 1000), localPendingIntent);

    }

    Log.d("TAG", "Sync------");

}
```

Here i'm splitting hour,minutes because my settings contains 15 Minutes, 1 Hour and so on you can set it as per your requirement like day ,week etc

```
public class NotificationServiceSyncInterval extends IntentService {

public NotificationServiceSyncInterval() {
    super("Sync Tracker Online");

}

public NotificationServiceSyncInterval(String paramString) {
    super(paramString);

}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {


    Log.d("TAG", "Sync Handler call");
    // todo
    callSync();

}

public static void callSync() {

    try {
        //Your Sync Code here

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Manifest Entry for above class

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.yourpackage.TimerReceiverSyncInterval"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.yourpackage.NotificationServiceSyncInterval" >
    </service>
```

And finally assign the context when user select the time interval i.e     TimerReceiverSyncInterval.scheduleAlarms(this);

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what would be the best way to do it. But you could make a `SharedPreference` variable like `LastSyncTime` which will contain the time of the sync and update this value every time your sync occurs in `onPerformSync()` in which you actually synced data.

The next time `onPerformSync()` is called then you could compare your `LastSyncTime` value with the current time value. If it's been a week already then perform the sync and update the `LastSyncTime's` value otherwise don't perform the sync i.e. exit the `onPerformSync()` method without executing anything.

Answer (score 0):

use `android:isAlwaysSyncable="false"` in `syncadapter.xml` after that it work as expected(not automatically sync when internet available).

---

`android:isAlwaysSyncable`  Indicates to the sync adapter framework that it can run your sync adapter at any time you've specified. If you want to programmatically control when your sync adapter can run, set this flag to false, and then call `requestSync()` to run the sync adapter.

read [documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#CreateSyncAdapterMetadata)

Comment: I had set  android:isAlwaysSyncable="false" but it did not help. When ever I turn on the internet the sync adapter gets called and all the data gets synced.

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the moment you create the user account linked to the sync service:

```
if (accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, null)) {

    // Inform the system that this account supports sync
    ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, BuildConfig.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, 1)

    // Inform the system whether this account is eligible for auto sync when the network 
    // is up. In your case should be false
    ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, BuildConfig.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, false)

    // Add a schedule for automatic synchronisation. The system may call the sync function
    // a few seconds early or late for battery and network optimisation.
    ContentResolver.addPeriodicSync(account, BuildConfig.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, Bundle(), 
            SYNC_FREQUENCY)
}
```